# Pandas group by start/end values

Tags: python, pandas

Given some data like

```
pd.DataFrame(list('SxxxxxxxxESxxxxESxxxxxxxxxxxxE'))
```

how can I form it into chunks starting with 'S' and ending with 'E'?

The real data is of course more complex, having one column with data like the above, and other columns that I want to use `groupby` on.

The end goal is to be able to retrieve and act on all S/E-delimited chunks meeting criteria from other columns (e.g., given mythical function `group_chunks` that does this, `myData.groupby('Person').group_chunks().Value.sum()`).

#### Update

Responding to a request for more-realistic data and desired output, the data looks something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PID': [1]*12+[2]*6,
                   'Cond': ['A']*6+['B']*6+['A']*6,
                   'Flag': ['START', 'DOWN', 'MOVE', 'MOVE', 'LIFT', 'END']*3, 
                   'Value': np.random.random(18)})

   Cond   Flag  PID     Value
0     A  START    1  0.156338
1     A   DOWN    1  0.706541
2     A   MOVE    1  0.569177
3     A   MOVE    1  0.308874
4     A   LIFT    1  0.150780
5     A    END    1  0.553462
6     B  START    1  0.028738
7     B   DOWN    1  0.512303
8     B   MOVE    1  0.975988
9     B   MOVE    1  0.735695
10    B   LIFT    1  0.094430
11    B    END    1  0.467895
12    A  START    2  0.114679
13    A   DOWN    2  0.911095
14    A   MOVE    2  0.359117
15    A   MOVE    2  0.819148
16    A   LIFT    2  0.505313
17    A    END    2  0.874462
```

So using the mythical `group_chunks` (and keeping in mind the number of rows between `START` and `END` is not always the same), I'd want to do something like

```
df.groupBy('PID').group_chunks('Flag', 'START', 'END').Value.sum()
```

to get a result something like

```
   Cond   PID   Value.sum
0     A     1    2.445172
1     B     1    2.347153
2     A     2    3.583813
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your real data and desired output? It's hard to know what you want from your description.

Comment: something like `(x.iloc[:,0] == 'S').cumsum()`, `cumsum` is you key method here

Comment: @Psidom - updated with some more realistic data.

Comment: Isn't this just `df.groupby(['Cond', 'PID']).Value.sum()`?

Comment: @Psidom No, because there may be more than one set of `START`/`END` groups per `Cond`/`PID`.

Comment: Don't how exactly your data is structured, possibly `df.groupby(['Cond', 'PID', (df.Flag == 'START').cumsum()]).Value.sum()`

Comment: Yes, the `(df.Flag == 'START').cumsum()` does it. Make that an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using numpy. It should at least get you started in the right direction. I gave your column a name "SE" for sake of convenience and readability:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list('SxxxxxxxxESxxxxESxxxxxxxxxxxxE'), columns=['SE'])

split_points = np.where(df['SE'] == 'E')[0] + 1 # array of after-"E" indices
found = np.array_split(df['data'], split_points) # split series
found = found[:-1] # remove the empty series at the end of the list
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you think using regex can help to solve the problem instead of processing string as list of characters? For example:

```
import re
pattern = r'S.+?E'
re.findall(pattern, 'SxxxxxxxxESxxxxESxxxxxxxxxxxxE')
```